# Azure API Management with Key Rotation

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-keyvault, azure-runbook

I am using KeyVault for storing `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`. Applications are getting this key from KeyVault and making requests to API Management successfully.

But now, i want to rotate this `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` frequently using powershell scripts in Runbooks. I can't find a way to regerenate `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` through powershell. Is this possible ? If there is another option to rotate this key then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible through API:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/regenerateprimarykey
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/regeneratesecondarykey

Should be somewhere in PS as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Get API Management Services information and set context
$ApiManagements = Get-AzApiManagement
foreach ($ApiManagement in $ApiManagements)
{
  $ApiManagementContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceId $ApiManagement.Id

  # Get all API Management Subscriptions
  $ApiManagementSubscriptions = Get-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $ApiManagementContext
  foreach ($ApiManagementSubscription in $ApiManagementSubscriptions)
  {
    # Update the Keys
    $PrimaryKey = (New-Guid) -replace '-',''
    $SecondaryKey = (New-Guid) -replace '-',''
    Set-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $ApiManagementContext -SubscriptionId $ApiManagementSubscription.SubscriptionId -PrimaryKey $PrimaryKey `
                                    -SecondaryKey $SecondaryKey -State Active 
  }
}
```